# How to move Search log files from C: Drive to E: to free space in C: Drive

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, crawl, logs

SharePoint Server C: Drive Space is full because if Search logs. I want to move the search log files from C: Drive to E: Drive.

How can I move these logs without affecting the SharePoint system?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: search logs or ULS logs?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? 10, 13, 16, 19? Enterprise or Foundation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use serach index you can use this function (it is for sp2013 but should work as well for later ones, in any case it will give you idea how to do it in powershell ) https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Move-SharePoint-2013-242869e2

if you problem is with ULS logs follow this advice how to do it in PowerShell:
https://www.techtask.com/moving-sharepoint-trace-and-usage-logs-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the ULS logs location via Central Administration > Monitoring > Configure diagnostic logging > Trace Log Path.

The location you specify must exist on all servers in the farm.

Reference:

[Change Log Files Location for ULS, Usage and Health Data Collection.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/04/change-log-file-location-diagnostic-uls-trace-log-usage-health-data-collection.html)